# If $\int f=0$, can I conclude that $f=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Suppose, $f:(0,1)\to\Re_+$ and $f\in L((0,1))$, therefore measurable. Is the following implication correct? 
$$\int_{(0,1)}f(x)\,d\mu=0\overset{?}{\implies} f(x)=0$$

Intuitively, I feel like the conclusion should hold because $f$ is a non negative function, but is there anyway of showing this?

Comment: No, we can only say that $f = 0$ almost everywhere, although if $f$ is also continuous, then the implication does hold, in the sense that $f = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
&{1\over q}\quad x={p\over q}\in\Bbb{Q}\\
&0\quad x\in\Bbb{R}-\Bbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

This function  is Lebesgue integrable with integral $0$

Comment: A few notes about formatting: when writing cases, you don't need an equals sign for each case. You can just do $f(x)=\begin{cases}1/q\\0\end{cases}$, which simplifies things. Also, if you want a space of a certain size in mathjax, there's [different codes for each space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing). e.g. \,\,\,\,\,\, = \quad.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting tips

Comment: @marwalix this is somewhat related, if $f(x)>0$ can I conclude $\int f(x)>0$?

Comment: Yes you can. Tedious to prove in the general setup